# Office 2010 prompts for login to SharePoint when editing local documents

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have MS Office 2010 installed and we have intranet sites using SharePoint 2007 and 2010.  When I open a document from my hard drive or create a new document in Word or Excel, I get a prompt to login to our SP 2007 site about every 10-15 minutes.  This is not when creating or editing documents on the SP site, but just random documents I have created on my own PC.  Whether I enter my info or click cancel doesn't seem to affect my ability to continue working on the document.  Entering my login info and checking the box to save my login credentials does not seem to stop it from prompting me again later in the day.

At the suggestion of another site, I have gone into File => Options => Save and altered the "Offline editing options for document management server files" to point to an explicitly-local folder, but it had no apparent effect.  Anyone know how to stop these prompts?  They are very distracting...

Comment: check [this](http://dinesql.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-always-prompts-for-login.html) and [this](http://spfarm.blogspot.com/2011/05/sharepoint-always-prompts-for.html)

Comment: Do you have SharePoint Workspace installed?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Both of those links deal with logging into the SharePoint site when you visit the site.  Logging in there would be expected, but this is Office requesting the login, and it happens even when my browser is closed and I have made no attempt to get to the site.  I can have a freshly-booted machine, never open a browser or SP Designer, and a few mins after creating a new Word/Excel doc it will prompt me to login to the SP 2007 site.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I do have it installed, but I have never used it.  I tried opening it just now and it's not even configured.

Comment: @techturtle I was asking because there is this background application `msosync.exe`. I was wondering if that might get started by you starting Word/Excel/... and trying to periodically sync with SharePoint in the background.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I do see that running in the background.  For now I tried clearing the cached documents it was holding.  If that doesn't work I'll try shutting it off.  I hesitate to kill it, because I think it's responsible for syncing my OneNote books that are online, and I still need that feature (the OneNote login process is different though, so I know they aren't causing the problem).

Comment: You could use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and drag that little crosshair on the login dialog that appears. This will highlight the process it belongs to in Process Explorer. This could show if the login is requested by the Office application you started (or another process).

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same issue, and finally found that it is caused by the Recent Items. In that list, if you clear out any and all links to documents that reside in the sharepoint environment and you're not connected directly, you will get these prompts. Haven't found a solution tho (other than removing the links). Huge annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues like this that were resolved when I went to the main templates that I was using for new documents and performed this action: File > Info > Check for Issues > Inspect Document > Document Properties and Personal Information > Inspect > Remove All

All new documents created with these templates no longer have this issue, and the ones created with the older version of the template had to have that action manually performed on each one. It is Document Server Properties that get stuck in the document if it is based off of a template that was retrieved from a SharePoint library.